# Disable addtocart button when products is empty in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

i need to disable the cart button when there is no product in the cart and if we add the product the button should be enabled.
my Code as follow:

```
@if (!isset($data['cart'])) 
    <div class="tt-cart-list">
        @if( isset($data['cartlist']['count']))
            @foreach ($data['cartlist']['data'] as $list)
                <h2 class="tt-title">{{ $list['ItemName'] }}</h2>
                    @endforeach
                       <h6 style="color: #1b9051;">Oops, You have no item</h6>
                           @endif
                               </div>
                                   @endif

                                    <a href="{{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/AddtoCart')}}" class="btn">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just conditionally print `href` attribute of `<a>` tag

```
<a @if (isset($data['cart'])) href="{{url('/Shop/'.$data['webname'].'/AddtoCart')}}"@endif class="btn">PROCEED TO CHECKOUT</a>
```

Comment: Seva Kalashnikov the button is disabled but if it have products the button not enabled

Comment: is `Oops, You have no item` displayed properly when cart empty and hidden otherwise? @jaison

Comment: @ Seva Kalashnikov also, I need to disable the button when there are no products in the cart. now the cart btn is disabled but when I added the products the button needs to enable

Comment: @jaison you'll have to troubleshoot this by yourself, I gave you a hint on how to conditionally remove href from the link button so it becomes inactive, now you need to combine it with correct `@if` statement that represents empty card